# In text preprocessing, Contractions are not recognising single and double quotes

Tags: nlp, python-3.7

I am doing text preprocessing of my text which is articles.
In my preprocessing code, one of the steps is contractions where I am trying to expand words like " I've " , " I'm " etc. 
But I am facing an issue where contraction is working when I type the sample text but I don't work on my text. 
I also know the reason. The reason is that there is a difference in the font. 
For example the sample text:

**“I’m here because a Cabinet minister is needed.”**

And below is the same text but I wrote by myself:

**"I'm here because a Cabinet minister is needed."**

If you look carefully you can see the difference in the quotation marks (both single and double).

How do I solve this issue?

Below is the code which I am using for contractions.

```
def expand_contractions(row, contraction_mapping=CONTRACTION_MAP):
    Japan_3 = row['Articles']
    Japan_3 = Japan_3.apply(lambda x: str(x).replace("’", "'"))
    contractions_pattern = re.compile('({})'.format('|'.join(contraction_mapping.keys())),
                                      flags=re.IGNORECASE | re.DOTALL)

    def expand_match(contraction):
        match = contraction.group(0)
        first_char = match[0]
        expanded_contraction = contraction_mapping.get(match) \
            if contraction_mapping.get(match) \
            else contraction_mapping.get(match.lower())
        expanded_contraction = first_char + expanded_contraction[1:]
        return expanded_contraction

    expanded_text = contractions_pattern.sub(expand_match, Japan_3)
    expanded_text = re.sub("'", "", expanded_text)
    return expanded_text


Japan['expanded_text'] = Japan.apply(expand_contractions, axis=1)
```

After altering the code I am getting below error:

> AttributeError: ("'str' object has no attribute 'apply'", 'occurred at
>   index 0')

I don't know how to explain it in a less confusing way.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Isn't easier to convert the contraction quote to a single one? You can run a simple replace command to convert all quotation marks from one kind to the one that works and then just execute that one. For example: string.replace("'","'"), which makes I’m into I'm. Then just use your code to convert I'm to I am. Would it work? Or do you really need the two forms of quotation marks?

Comment: Yes, it would definitely work. Can you tell me the line of code? I am working on pandas and I have a column name 'Articles', so I am writing like: Japan = pd.read_csv("Japan.csv")
Japan['Articles'] = Japan['Articles'].string.replace("'","'") But it is showing error: AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'string'

Comment: I answered the question, please check if my solution suits your purpose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A solution could be to replace all the wrong contraction mark to the correct one. In your case, this can be done by applying a replace function to the Article column in Pandas Dataframe:

```
Japan_3 = Japan_3.apply(lambda x:str(x).replace("’","'"))
```

I can't test your function because I don't have your contraction mapping you are passing as parameter. But my guess is that you can add that piece of code after `Japan_3 = row['Articles']`. Then execute the rest of your contraction as normal. In fact, I'd call the function in this way:

```
expand_contractions(Japan, contraction_mapping=CONTRACTION_MAP)
```

But, to be sincere, I don't know exactly what are you trying to do in that code to remove the contractions. To be fair, to expand contractions I'd just replace each but their expanded form in the text. The following is what I'd do. I didn't test it, though, so it might not work accordingly, but I guess it is similar.

```
CONTRACTION_MAP = {"I'm":"I am"} # contraction definition. This is just an example, please change it here with your contractions
Japan["Article"] = Japan["Article"].apply(lambda x:str(x).replace("’","'")) # replace the wrong quotation mark by the correct one
for contraction in CONTRACTION_MAP:
    Japan["Article"] = Japan["Article"].apply(lambda x:str(x).replace(contraction,CONTRACTION_MAP[contraction])) # in this case I'm just replacing the contraction by the expanded form. I iterate it through all the possible contractions
```

Comment: Where do I have to put the new line of code? After Japan_3 = row['Articles']? It is showing an error if I put it there. Is it okay if I edit the code in my question with your line of code? Maybe then it would be easy for you to tell?

Comment: I have updated the code in my answer! Please check and tell me if it is correct or I made a mistake!

Comment: There are some unclear things on what you're doing. 1- In your updated code, when you call Japan.apply I don't think that's the correct way to call expand_contractions function. Why don't you just call expand_contractions(Japan, contraction_mapping=CONTRACTION_MAP)? 2- Another way would be to iterate through the contraction mappings you have and apply the mapping to the string. Would it work? I'll update the answer to show the different ways to solve it.

Comment: Thank you so much! I used your code and it worked! Thanks again!

Comment: Thank you! Which one of them worked for you? The modifications in how to call your function? Or my loop through the contractions?

Comment: I used your loop!